# Pyspark - Sort dataframe column that contains list of list

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below -

```
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| WindowID | State |                                         Details |
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|        6 |    SD | [[29916,3], [156570,4], [245934,1], [329748,8]] |
|        3 |    CO |              [[524586,2], [1548,3], [527220,1]] |
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, i want to sort every row of `Details` column in descending order based on the second element of list. Result should be -

```
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| WindowID | State |                                         Details |
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|        6 |    SD | [[329748,8], [156570,4], [29916,3], [245934,1]] |
|        3 |    CO |              [[1548,3], [524586,2], [527220,1]] |
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

How can i do it in pyspark? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple trick for this problem -

```
import operator

mydf = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[6, 'SD', [[29916,3], [156570,4], [245934,1], [329748,8]]],
           [3, 'CO', [[524586,2], [1548,3], [527220,1]]]],
           ['WindowID', 'State', 'Details']).show(truncate=False)

+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| WindowID | State |                                         Details |
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|        6 |    SD | [[29916,3], [156570,4], [245934,1], [329748,8]] |
|        3 |    CO |              [[524586,2], [1548,3], [527220,1]] |
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+

sorted_df = mydf.rdd.map(lambda x: [x[0], x[1], sorted(x[2], \ 
          key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]) \
          .toDF(['WindowID', 'State', 'Details']) \
          .show(truncate=False)

+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| WindowID | State |                                         Details |
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|        6 |    SD | [[329748,8], [156570,4], [29916,3], [245934,1]] |
|        3 |    CO |              [[1548,3], [524586,2], [527220,1]] |
+----------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How would you sort the Details column if that column was the result of arrays_zip (that produces list of sets). Like this: [{a, 0.92}, {b, 0.8}, {d, 0.65}, {c, 0.99}]. The result I would want is: [{c, 0.99}, {a, 0.92}, {b, 0.8}, {d, 0.65}].

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your tried, but check below solution this will work for you.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

dfSchema = StructType([StructField('WindowID', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('State', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Details', ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())), True)])
#["WindowID", "State", "Details"]
mydf = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[6, 'SD', [[29916,3], [156570,4], [245934,1], [329748,8]]],
[3, 'CO', [[524586,2], [1548,3], [527220,1]]]], dfSchema)
mydf.show(truncate = False)

+--------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|WindowID|State|Details                                                                                            |
+--------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|6       |SD   |[WrappedArray(29916, 3), WrappedArray(156570, 4), WrappedArray(245934, 1), WrappedArray(329748, 8)]|
|3       |CO   |[WrappedArray(524586, 2), WrappedArray(1548, 3), WrappedArray(527220, 1)]                          |
+--------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

def def_sort(x):
        return sorted(x, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

udf_sort = udf(def_sort, ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))
mydf.select("windowID", "State", udf_sort("Details")).show(truncate = False)


+--------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|windowID|State|PythonUDF#def_sort(Details)                                                                        |
+--------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|6       |SD   |[WrappedArray(329748, 8), WrappedArray(156570, 4), WrappedArray(29916, 3), WrappedArray(245934, 1)]|
|3       |CO   |[WrappedArray(1548, 3), WrappedArray(524586, 2), WrappedArray(527220, 1)]                          |
+--------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```